iOS: SKStoreReviewController Is deprecated. how to use RequestReviewAction on project objective C?
I'm currently working on an iOS project written in Objective-C and recently noticed that SKStoreReviewController seems to have been deprecated. From what I've gathered, there's a new method called RequestReviewAction that replaces the in-app review request process.
However, I'm having trouble finding documentation or examples on how to implement RequestReviewAction in Objective-C code.
Could anyone guide me on how to use RequestReviewAction or integrate the new review request method in an Objective-C project?
Thank you so much for your help!

I don't not how about Objective-C project. UIKit i found this solution.
   if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }) as? UIWindowScene {
        if #available(iOS 18, *) {
            AppStore.requestReview(in: scene)
        } else {
            SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
        }
    }

AppStore.requestReview(in: scene) - minimum IOS version 16.0

This is Swift code.

Yes, swift code. UIKit.

Looking at the documentation here, you can see that this is supported only in SwiftUI and therefore, not available in Objective C.

As opposed to SKStoreReviewController,


Thank you. So, when SKStoreReviewController is no longer supported, will apps that use Objective-C be unable to perform in-app reviews? Or will there be an alternative solution that has not yet been announced?

@Alexandro - That is a question best aimed at Apple. If my answer helped you, please mark it as such, so others can find it more easily.
